# Ito's Lemma for negative exponential

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I'd been reading on Hull-White model, when I encountered the bond-pricing formula, that is if

$$ dr(t) = (\alpha(t)-\beta(t)r(t))dt + \sigma(t)dW(t)$$

for some deterministic function $\alpha, \beta, \sigma$, and $W$ being the Wiener process, then the zero bond price at time $t$ with maturity $T$ is given by

$$B(t,T)=\exp(-r(t)C(t,T)-A(t,T))$$

where $C(t,T)$ and $A(t,T)$ are completely deterministic; they are determined by $\alpha(t)$, $\beta(t)$, and $\sigma(t)$.

When I want to derive $dB(t,T)$, I want to use Ito's Lemma, so here are my steps:

---

Assuming $T$ is fixed, $B$ is determined by a process $r$ and time $t$, thus letting
$$f(x,t) = \exp(-xC(t,T)-A(t,T))$$
We have:

$$f_x = -C(t,T) f(x,t), f_{xx} = C(t,T)^2f(x,t), f_t = \left[-xC_t(t,T)-A_t(t,T)\right]f(x,t)$$

Thus according to Ito's Lemma,

$$dB(t,T)=f_x(r(t),t)dr(t)+\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(r(t),t)dr(t)dr(t)+f_t(r(t),t)dt$$
$$=B(t,T)\left[-C(t,T)dr(t)+\frac{1}{2}C(t,T)^2dr(t)dr(t)-r(t)C_t(t,T)dt-A_t(t,T)dt\right]$$

---

However, as it turns out, this is incorrect; the correct answer, which is due to the expression of $A(t,T)$ and $C(t,T)$ (which I will give later as I think we should be able to obtain $dB(t,T)$ without looking at $A(t,T)$ and $C(t,T)$), is

$$dB(t,T)=B(t,T)\left[-C(t,T)dr(t)-\frac{1}{2}C(t,T)^2dr(t)dr(t)-r(t)C_t(t,T)dt-A_t(t,T)dt\right]$$

I managed to obtain this correct answer though, by an algebraic manipulation (which I'm also not sure is valid, or not):

---

Consider the fact that
$$B(t,T)\exp(r(t)C(t,T)+A(t,T))=1$$
Then, taking the differential,
$$dB(t,T)\exp(r(t)C(t,T)+A(t,T)) + B(t,T)d\left[\exp(r(t)C(t,T)+A(t,T))\right] = 0$$

Now, by Ito's Lemma, we have
$$d\left[\exp(r(t)C(t,T)+A(t,T))\right]$$
$$=\exp(r(t)C(t,T)+A(t,T))\cdot$$
$$\left[C(t,T)dr(t)+\frac12C(t,T)^2dr(t)dr(t)+r(t)C_t(t,T)dt+A_t(t,T)dt\right]$$

Using this fact and cancelling out $\exp(r(t)C(t,T)+A(t,T))$, we have

$$dB(t,T)+B(t,T)\left[C(t,T)dr(t)+\frac12C(t,T)^2dr(t)dr(t)+r(t)C_t(t,T)dt+A_t(t,T)dt\right]=0$$
and we have:
$$dB(t,T)=B(t,T)\left[-C(t,T)dr(t)-\frac{1}{2}C(t,T)^2dr(t)dr(t)-r(t)C_t(t,T)dt-A_t(t,T)dt\right]$$

---

**Why is my first derivation incorrect, yet my second derivation correct?**

Note:

This is the explicit form of $A(t,T)$ and $C(t,T)$. Firstly, let

$$K(t)=\int_0^t\beta(u)du$$

then

$$A(t,T)=\int_t^T\left[e^{K(v)}\alpha(v)\left(\int_v^Te^{-K(y)}dy\right)-\frac12e^{2K(v)}\sigma(v)^2\left(\int_v^Te^{-K(y)}dy\right)^2\right]dv$$

$$C(t,T)=e^{K(t)}\left(\int_t^Te^{-K(y)}dy\right)$$

Thank you! I am still self-studying on stochastic calculus, and as such I still don't have a strong grip on the concept itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the first derivation is correct. In the second derivation, taking the differential of $B \exp(rC + A)$ gives $$B d(\exp(rC+A)) + \exp(rC+A)dB + (dB)(d(\exp(rC+A)).$$ The extra term $(dB)(d(\exp(rC+A))$ is where the $C^2(dr)(dr)$ difference comes from.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However according to the formula for A and C, I was expecting the dt term of dB(t, T) to be r(t) (risk-neutral pricing), which is true iff the formula from second derivative is true. Usually, what's the correct approach on this problem?